# Play audio with more than one file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do i play audio
In more than one file
Where I can move between pages without stopping sounds
I see it a lot in games
I hope to get your answer

Answer (score 0):

It depends on callback function `onDestroys()` because your App works as a process in the Androids OS when you change the Activity the `stopService()` kill the music playing in your current activity.

Do not call the `stopService()` method.

Comment: My friend when I run the sound
Works normally
But when you go to another page
The sound will stop
I do not want to stop :)

Comment: With another page you mean new activity?

Comment: I do not want to stop sound when navigating between pages

Comment: Can you create a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Create MediaPlayer object outside onCreate()

```
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

Then do create inside onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.dali); //R.raw.dali is directory from folder raw that i made and the file name is dali
        mediaPlayer.start(); //start the song
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true); //set the song to loop if you want it play forever (true) and if you dont want to loop (false)
}
```

(let say this code is in MainActivity.class) whenever activity that you dont want to play the song just call

```
MainActivity.mediaPlayer.stop();
```

Comment: When the sound is playing
  It executes once
  Then stop must only be repeated?

Comment: Yes, it only executes once and playing once then stop. So, if you want the song repeat after it's done, you set the loop become true. You can stop whenever you want and calls MediaPlayer.stop();